# PDF Opens in Korean in Firefox, but opens in Chinese in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I have a a PDF that has been created, it should be in Chinese which when I view it in the Chrome Browser it works perfectly. However, when you open it in Firefox it displays in Korean (!). What has happened that would mean this could happen?

http://www.jaguar.com.cn/Images/XF_14MY_MB_CHI_tcm100-58191.pdf

This can happen either just using the file in the link, or by downloading the file and then dragging it into the browser window.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat, it shows in chinese.

There may be one problem with the document, which is that not all fonts are marked as embedded. Those CID fonts do have a specific encoding. It is now possible that the Firefox PDF viewer is improperly interpreting the font family to use and/or the encoding.

In short, just so, I don't see much you can do about the document. OK, one thing which might help would be checking the font options for Firefox.